# Angular.js and displaying Rest JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I'm a newbie to Angular and I'm doing some prototyping. Unfortunately when I call a REST service I'm having issues displaying the data. The console is not providing clues because no errors come back.

HTML is below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="statViewer">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Test Angular Page</title>

    <script  src="js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script  src="js/statViewer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">

    <h1> {{title}} </h1>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="stat in stats">
            <td>{{stat.MessageName}}</td>
            <td>{{stat.TypeCount}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

JS is below:

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module("statViewer", []);

    var MainController = function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.title = "Angular test page";

        $http.get("http://localhost:8080/API/getstats.json")
            .then(onStatsComplete);

        var onStatsComplete = function(response)
        {
            $scope.stats = response.data;
        };


    };

    app.controller("MainController", MainController);

}());
```

I see that the service is being called because on the console window it prints out that the call was triggered. Result of the REST API being invoked is here:

```
[
    {
        "TypeCount": 45,
        "SentDate": "2014-08-20T00:00:00.000Z",
        "MessageName": "Message Type 1"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the variable `onStatsComplete` with your callback function *after* the call to `$http.get`.  So at the point in time when you are making the call to `$http.get` the value `undefined` is passed to then rather than your callback function.  Swap the lines around like this:

```
    var onStatsComplete = function(response)
    {
        $scope.stats = response.data;
    };

    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/API/getstats.json")
        .then(onStatsComplete);
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) on the difference between writing `var y = function(){...}` and `function y(){...}`.

Answer (score 0):

To give more insight, when ever you do $http.get call.

Every $http call is Aysncronous in angularJs.

```
   $http.get("http://localhost:8080/API/getstats.json")
            .then(function(result){   
console.log(result.TypeCount);
               });
```

Let me know if you still unable to get the data.